# validate checkbox in a function and return results

Tags: php, function

I've created a small function that validates a checkbox control in a form. Im not sure about arrays in functions...

Does the return in the function actually returns an array?

Do i need to declare $arr_category as an array?
In other words, does my function makes sense, need to improve something?

```
function val_checkbox($name, $required = false) {
    global $warning;
    $value = array();

    if(isset($_POST[$name])) {
        $value = $_POST[$name];

    } else {
        if ($required) {
            $warning[$name] = "Required field!";
        }
    }

    return $value;
}

$arr_category = val_checkbox('category'); // category
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've no clue for this function not working !

`$value` will be an array, no need to declare `$arr_caterogy` as an array.

It's seem working for me.

Comment: Sorry, I did not specify that the function works perfectly and that I need it to know if I also needed to declare $arr_category as an array or it will inherit the type... you've answered my question: no need to declare $arr_category as an array because it will inherit the type array by the return value. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
function val_checkbox($name, $required = false)
{
    global $warning;
    $value = false;
    if(isset($_POST[$name])) $value = $_POST[$name];
    else
    {
        if ($required) $warning[$name] = "Required field!";
    }
    return $value;
}
$arr_category = val_checkbox('category');
```

So you can get `false` as return value if it's invalidated, otherwise the value of the check box will be returned and no need to declare the `$arr_category` as an array.